# Linux Java Emoji ( 3 words xD )

Tags: java, linux, terminal, emoji, raspberry-pi-os

I work on a project and I need to display emojis (Apple Color Emoji or Noto or other ) on a jpanel jlabel etc on Java on Linux ( RPI OS )

my program launches very well on my Mac. photo :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoNVv.png)

Linux jdk java 17.0.9 17/10/2023 ( same on macOS and linux )

I know it possible because macOS and linux are build similar. and i've already had monochrome emojis on my java on linux.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utpc5.jpg)

I don't have problem with the display other than on java, Geany and terminal display it well:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpGfo.jpg)

Comment: You need to check your font support for emojis on the OS first by independent means. I'd advise you to remove the French text as it might be deemed unacceptable by moderators, even though you posted in English too

Comment: Hello, Thank you. I have updated.
But theses emojis work well on terminal and Geany. like I said I had these in monochrome before.

Comment: OK, since I assume we're talking about direct font support for rocket emojis, shall be fix on one, say `U+1F680`?

Comment: https://www.noelshack.com/2024-11-2-1710247718-capture-d-ecran-2024-03-12-a-13-48-28.png   Doesn't change anything. Of course Noto doesn't display something cause it is not installed on my Mac. but other unicode is displayed well

Comment: How about this? `JLabel emojiLabel = new JLabel(Character.toString(0x1F680));`

Comment: https://www.noelshack.com/2024-11-2-1710248001-img-2348.jpg but Apple Color Emoji is the only one to display nothing

Comment: on my MacBook every font work well and display rocket but on linux nothing

Comment: It's not a Linux thing per se. `echo 'System.out.println("\ud83d\ude80");' | jshell` works fine for me

Comment: https://www.noelshack.com/2024-11-2-1710248227-capture-d-ecran-2024-03-12-a-11-38-08.png on macOS and https://www.noelshack.com/2024-11-2-1710248270-img-2349.jpg on linux

Comment: if in java code I make a button containing the emoji and when it's pressed it sends its value to the terminal, it won't appear in the jlabel but in the terminal there's no problem.

Comment: the fact that the button contains emoji, it not appear on swing but it display on terminal with no problem : 
https://www.noelshack.com/2024-11-2-1710248755-img-2350.jpg

Comment: linux display well emoji on Geany and terminal. it's just Java. but other than Apple color emoji show square unicode not find. but not apple emoji color. but work very well on my Mac so I'm lost

Comment: I try this :

        JLabel emojiLabel1 = new JLabel("\uD83D\uDE80");
        JLabel emojiLabel2 = new JLabel("\u1F680");
        JLabel emojiLabel3 = new JLabel("");
        JLabel emojiLabel4 = new JLabel(Character.toString(0x1F680));
        
but nothing
        
        add(panel);

Comment: Try setting a font of SansSerif

Comment: something appear but ... not emoji. see the link https://www.noelshack.com/2024-11-2-1710251165-img-2352.jpg I have try with Roboto, it is good ?

Comment: A named one that might do it is *Symbola*

Comment: I can display most emoji characters in Swing without any special fonts, on Debian/Gnome.  Have you tried displaying those characters without setting any fonts at all?

Comment: I added with apt install fonts-symbola
so I have :
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ancient-scripts/Symbola_hint.ttf: Symbola:style=Regular
i have this https://www.noelshack.com/2024-11-2-1710264409-img-2353.jpg

Comment: Well it looks like rockets have appeared at least ;)

Comment: yes I try, but same result.

Comment: I already have monochromatic emoji, it's good but not enough, I dont' know why, with you, I pretty sure to achieved it xDD

Comment: if I export my .java in jar file on my macOS then execute it on linux, it can create issues ?

With Symbola installed, emoji are become google/noto emoji, no longer from apple emojis ( not a big deal but not accurate ahah )

Comment: Surely the point of having font support is so you don't have to use an image. Fonts don't *have* colour (only when they're styled)

Comment: yeah, but work well on java swing macOS. or like VGR doesn't seem to have issues with his emojis. I try everything I have no idea anymore to unlock this.. I'm sure it's not much...

Comment: it can't come from fonts.conf or local.conf ? or other ?

Comment: Should be OK in a jar. Try [THIS](https://technojeeves.com/tech/rocket.jar) (contains source too)

Comment: I don't know what you dev but : 


Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class F
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: F has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 65.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 61.0

I'm on java idk 17.0.9

Comment: Oops sorry, that's the one thing I forgot ;) Download it again. It's now 1.9

Comment: yes, I understand what you try. like I said before, the terminal work week I have a real color emojis but the frame/window it's a monochromatic emoji. please HELP ME xDDDD

Comment: Well you've probably got images if they are in colour, not a font

Comment: in the terminal ? don't think the terminal can display image. when you say image you talk about "glyphe". I'm sure we are not far from the answer..

Comment: in fact, your jar dive me the same on macOS. terminal ok but no on java.

Comment: Sorry, glyphs, yes. I'm trying the same with Noto itself but nothing is appearing, despite the font saying it can render the character

Comment: it obviously can !! macOS work well and pretty same as linux.
emoji monochromatic are not as far as the color emoji ^^. 
Emojis is recognised on terminal and Geany. maybe a setting or other.
I try too with Noto because Noto is a real install on package, not like Apple color emoji ..

Comment: At the moment I'm loading Noto dynamically as I don't want to install it

Comment: I don't understand why linux/emoji/java are no result on internet..

Comment: I couldn't find a single example of a pure Java usage of NotoEmoji by googling. Virtually no Android either

Comment: me too, otherwise I couldn't have the question on this forum. but it's obviously possible.

Comment: maybe should I change os ? like gnome ?

Comment: honestly tried everything. if somebody avec the answer... no emoji on java swing on linux raspbian..